# PHP urlencode returning unexpected results

Tags: php, urlencode

I'm attempting to encode the following using urlencode:

```
 <t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t
```

which should be encoded as:

```
 %3Ct%3ARequestSecurityTokenResponse+xmlns%3At
```

However, the result of urlencode is this:

```
 %26lt%3Bt%3ARequestSecurityTokenResponse+xmlns%3At
```

I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious here, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: tested this on https://paiza.io/projects/uIImHXniUZUuy4g3EE5foA and it's work , can u show us your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The front of your encoded string looks like the html entity for <.  It appears what you are passing to urlencode has been run through htmlentities.

```
php > echo urlencode("<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t");
%3Ct%3ARequestSecurityTokenResponse+xmlns%3At
php > echo urlencode("&lt;t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t");
%26lt%3Bt%3ARequestSecurityTokenResponse+xmlns%3At
```

Comment: That was it...thanks.  The string I was converting was from a cURL response, and instead of writing it to a file I was viewing it in a browser with var_dump, making the HTML entities appear as their actual characters.  I knew it was something simple.  Thank you!